# MySQL RDS - Unable to Kill Hung Queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL RDS instance that's got 100+ queries all stuck waiting for a table metadata lock.

#### The good news

I have permission to kill all of the sessions, and have 0 concern for data loss as this database is completely reloaded as needed.

#### The bad news

It's a MySQL instance running as a hosted RDS instance in AWS **AND** while I have access to the "root" MySQL account, I don't have access to the AWS console that this RDS instance is hosted in.

#### What I've tried

When this has happened previously, I look through the connections and run `CALL mysql.rds_kill(_each_and_every_process_id_one_at_a_time)`. However, this time, when I try run one of these kill statements, it simply hangs. (I'm doing this through MySQL workbench)

What options do I have? Is there someway to "escalate" my `mysql.rds_kill` call so that it's handled right away? Do I try executing this outside of workbench somehow?

Comment: In `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, which query has the highest "Time"?  Can you kill it?

Comment: Check the free storage space for the RDS instance, in the console.  Lack of free disk could cause a hang.  Also check the error log in the console for unusual entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite Workbench freezing on me, I was able to connect to the MySQL instance via the command line and run `CALL mysql.rds_kill(_each_and_every_process_id_one_at_a_time)` successfully.